# How to add a layout to a customlayout?

Tags: android

I want to add layouts to a custom view just like this:

```
public DropDown(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        
        init(attrs , context);
    }
    public void init(AttributeSet attrs , Context context) {

 TypedArray array = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs , R.styleable.DropDown , 0 , 0);

        try {

            b = array.getBoolean(R.styleable.DropDown_show_text , true);
            drawable = array.getDrawable(R.styleable.DropDown_android_drawableEnd);
            rows = array.getInt(R.styleable.DropDown_sections , 0);

        }finally {

            array.recycle();

        }


        Toast.makeText(context, "Rows:" + rows, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setOrientation(VERTICAL);

        for (int i = 0 ; i<rows ; i++) {

             View view = (LinearLayout) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main , this);

            LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
            layout.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(androidx.cardview.R.color.cardview_shadow_end_color));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT , 100);
            params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;

            layout.setLayoutParams(params);


            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

            layout.addView(view);

             addView(view , i);



        }




    }


}
```

I want to create a dropdown list.For that I want to dynamically add views to a custom layout which extends linear layout.addView(layout) doesn't work.Any solutions will be welcomed.Inflating a layout also doesnt work.

I want to add layouts to a custom layout which is linear layout in my case.How to achieve it?